# Проблема при установке драйвера MongoDB для C++ под Linux

Tags: c++, mongodb, драйвер

Устанавливаю в соответсвии с https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Quickstart-Guide-%28New-Driver%29

Драйвер C устанавливается великолепно. На этапе установки драйвера C++ (cmake) пишет:

```
CMake Error at cmake/FindLibBSON.cmake:23 (message):
  Don't know how to find libbson; please set LIBBSON_DIR to the prefix
  directory with which libbson was configured.
```

Где, как установить эту проклятую LIBBSON_DIR? Гуглю, но видать ни у кого с LIBBSON_DIR еще проблем не было, в гугле ноль ответов вообще на "LIBBSON_DIR".

Сами по себе библиотеки libson имеются (в /usr/lib), но как ни натравливал на них LIBBSON_DIR, все одно и тоже

Answer (score 1):

Удачно установил и использовал так называемый Legacy Driver. Тот, что упоминается в вопросе, еще нестабилен и плохо документирован. Инструкции для установки: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/wiki/Download-and-Compile-the-Legacy-Driver

> **Хочу обратить внимание на грабли!**

При компиляции драйвера с помощью scons, зачем-то, по умолчанию стоит опция "воспринимать предупреждения как ошибку", что не дает откомпилировать весь проект, так как он содержит warning, что переменная инициализированна, но не используется. В общем, надо указать при компиляции опцию --disable-warnings-as-errors. Кроме того, приложение в С++ (использующее драйвер) откомпилировалось, но не заработало, пока я не перекомпилировал **драйвер** с явным указанием на C++11, то есть, командная строка у меня выглядела так:

```
scons --disable-warnings-as-errors --prefix=$HOME/mongo-client-install --c++11=on  install
```

и все прекрасно заработало! В остальном можно смело доверять инструкции.

Answer (score 0):

Новый C++ драйвер уже довольно стабилен, так что не вижу причин им не пользоваться.
Как написано в инструкции - для сборки C++ драйвера надо сначала собрать `libbson` и `mongo-c-driver`. У меня они собираются в одну и ту же папку ( опция `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<path>`).
Далее при сборке C++ дрвайвера указываем этот путь(пути) в параметрах:

```
cd mongo-cxx-driver
cmake [...] -DLIBBSON_DIR=<path-to-libbson-build-dir> -DLIBMONGOC_DIR=<path-to-mongo-c-driver-build-dir>
```